# Nonparametric Test for Index Sufficiency Assumption

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics, nonparametric

I wanted to ask a questions about the following problem I was presented. I was thinking of doing an OLS vs a SLS for part a and running a Hausman, but I am just unsure if that would be the right way to proceed. Any insight would be incredibly helpful.

[image]